# How do you know if a function can be represented as a convergent power series in terms of analyticity and singularities?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I was reading my textbook on Fourier Analysis and it reads,

"Let $F(z)$ be an analytic function of the complex variable $z = x + iy$, without singularities for $|z| \leq 1$. Then $F(z)$ can be expanded in a power series..."

How do you know if a function in the Complex plane can be represented as a convergent power series merely based on analyticity and singularities? What about for a function in the Reals?

Disclaimer: **I have looked at similar questions, but they have not answered my particular question.**

Comment: That's the *definition* of analytic at a point, that it can be expanded in a power series in a neighborhood of the point.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: The definition of $f(z)$ being analytic at $z_0$ is that $f$ can be expanded as a power series in a neighborhood of $z_0$.  That's literally the definition of "analytic" so it doesn't make a lot of sense to ask how to know if a function can be expanded in a power series if we know that it is analytic.  If it's analytic then it can always be expanded as a power series - by definition.  I'm not sure what's hanging you up here.

Answer (score 1):

For complex analyticity search holomorphic functions and complex analysis.

Real analyticity is often proven via estimates for the derivatives.

Have you tried

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Real_versus_complex_analytic_functions

and there the third reference

http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195524081

which deals with real analyticity?

Answer (score 1):

It's a theorem of Complex Analysis that if $F(z)$ is analytic in  the disk $|z - a| < r$, then the Taylor series of $F(z)$ at $z=a$ converges in that disk.
See e.g. [these notes](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/winter99/ch9.pdf).